# Delete Button in tkinter tkk

Tags: tkinter, python-3.10

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import tkk
replay_btn = ttk.Button(game, text='Replay', command= lambda: replay_btn.forget())
replay_btn.grid(row=4,column=0)
```

Only text of button is clearing i want to clear whole button

Comment: replay_btn.destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure in the future that you are asking [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

You can simply use destroy() to solve your problem:

```
replay_btn = ttk.Button(game, text='Replay', command=lambda: replay_btn.destroy())
```